# Reading Tags in text File Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, text-files

so basically I have a text file setup something like this.

```
[IP] 192.168.22.12
[NAME] gtty
[COMMAND] i2203320
```

I wanna read everything in my file with tags so [IP] and then there's an IP above it witch I will be checking because these are gonna be some setting for a system that I am using the code I am using right now is this.

```
while line != '':

if (line == '[IP]'):
    List [0] == line[5:]
```

Its really not the best and I would like it to work better honestly. I have to setup if statements for every new line that I add and I just want it to be simpler like maybe having a list or something with named values and have it so when I read the file it will already be looking for the values and assign them to it.

```
nameList = ['[IP]': line.read()]
```

Just something Like that I understand the syntax on that one is probably wrong but im just trying to give an example so everyone knows what i'm trying to say.

regards BSD_,

Comment: You can do this with dictionaries. Just split the line, and use the [IP] as dictionary key. You won't need to check if the key exists then. If it doesnt exist it will be created, so you can create new settings without needing to adjust your code.

Comment: Could you just give an example of how to do this??

Comment: I have posted an answer that should work

Comment: @Stiffo good stuff man :) Thank you for the help :)

Comment: Is this a configuration file by any chance? if so look at ConfigParser [link](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/configparser.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do it with regular expression, very easy to parse:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'\[(.*?)\](.*)')

settings = {}

with open('your_file') as fd:
    for line in fd:
        m = pat.match(line)
        if m is None: continue
        settings[m.group(1)] = m.group(2).strip()
```

everything should be in `settings` now.

get IP info by:

```
ip = settings['IP']
```

reverse operation:

```
with open('your_file', 'w') as fd:
    for k, v in settings.items():
        fd.write('[{}] {}\n'.format(k, v))
```

Comment: hm.. seem to be getting an error.. "Expected::", could this be because of my python revision?

Comment: @BSD_ oh, that's because i switch to another input method accidentally when i typed a colon on the go. if you copy and paste my code, it was wrong. now it's ok.

Comment: Thank you so much for this :)

Comment: Hey uhm, how could you reverse this and write to a text file rather then read from it but write it like how I have it shown??

Comment: that's even much easier. it seems you are very new in python. it's very worthy to learn it seriously instead of picking it up piece by piece. you won't learn more in the latter way. i tried to learn things in latter way before but finally i found out i can learn way faster and maturer in shorter time by reading books and docs systematically.

Comment: Not nessecarly new lol my bad I was being lazy heres how to write it

[CODE]with open (file, 'w') as fp:
        for p in settings.items():
            fp.write("[%s]%s \n" % p)[/CODE]

Answer (score 1):

Add keys on array in object.

```
obj = {};
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        key = line.split()[0]
        try:
            obj[key]
        except:
            obj[key] = []
        obj[key].append(line.split()[1])
for key in obj:
    print key, obj[key]
```

Comment: Isn't this exactly what he asked not to get? An if-case for every tag/setting he's reading in.

Answer (score 1):

This will result in a dictionary of all settings in the file. This assumes the syntax of the file is consistently in the style described.

Input:

```
[IP] 192.168.22.12
[NAME] gtty
[COMMAND] i2203320

settings = {}
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.split()
        settings[items[0]] = ' '.join(items[1:])
```

Output:

```
{"[IP]":"192.168.22.12", "[NAME]":"gtty, "[COMMAND]":"i2203320"}
```

You could then get the IP or whatever setting when needed by calling `settings["[IP]"]`. And you can of course very easily edit this to only add lines that actually start with an [ ] item with just an extra if-case in there.